# How to add line break in Rmarkdown Word title using paste()?

Tags: r, text, export, r-markdown, export-to-word

I want to make a Word file using [rmarkdown](/questions/tagged/rmarkdown), and the title needs to be broken into 2 parts. Since the title is dynamic, I `paste()` the two pieces together.

This works:

```
---
title: "part 1  \n part 2"
output: word_document
---
```

But this does not work:

```
---
title: '`r paste("part 1", "part 2", sep = "  \\n ")`'
output: word_document
---
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Brecht, I figured out that if I place two spaces in front of \n, I can add a line break.  I don't have to use <div> .....</div> approach.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, I found a solution myself. Not very clean, but it does the trick:

```
---
output: word_document
---

<div custom-style="Title">
part `r 1`
</div>

<div custom-style="Title">
part `r 2`
</div>
```

(this of course requires that in your Word template, there is a style called 'Title')